# Obtener dirección IP interna de la conexión actual en Android

Tags: java, android

Necesito obtener la dirección IP del dispositivo cuando está conectado a una red, independientemente del tipo de conexión.

Conteplando las Posible conexiones de un dispositivo android:

- Conectado con Plan de datos mobile
- Conectado con Access point WIFI
- Conectado con Tethering Bluetooth
- Conectado con Tethering Wifi
- Conectado con Ethernet

### Datos Escenarios posibles

Todos los ejemplos que obtengo para obtener la dirección IP parten de `NetworkInterface` se basan en obtener la lista de las interficies de red, recorrerlas y obtener la dirección IP.

Eso si supongamos que solo existe una conexión realizada, se obtiene perfectamente la IP con la solución @Jorgesys que devuelve la última estancia con ipv4.

Pero si tienes el escenario de estar conectado con bluetooth mediante tethering y activado el wifi con una red seleccionada el icono del wifi esta con símbolo !.

Si listas la interficies la última es la de wifi, pero que no está conectada.

```
dummy0
bt-pan => esa es la que está conectada a internet
wlan0
```

Si desactivas el bluetooth.

```
dummy0
wlan0 => esa es la que está conectada a internet
```

Si se vuelve activar el bluetooth y reactivar la conexión al otro dispositivo para que comparte internet

```
dummy0
bt-pan => esa es la que está conectada a internet
wlan0
```

#### No encontrado como relacionar

No encuentro ninguna parte como relacionar la conexión establecida con su ip.

Para obtener el tipo de conexión que el dispositivo tiene establecida:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType()
```

Pero no encuentro ninguna variable que se pueda obtener la interfaz de red asociada es decir que devuelve `eth0,eth1..,wlan0,wlan1..` para después obtener su dirección ip.

Comment: Dejo un ejemplo que puede ser la solución http://www.android-examples.com/get-display-ip-address-of-android-phone-device-programmatically/

Answer (score 3):

Este es el método que utilizo.

```
   public static String getIP(){
        List<InetAddress> addrs;
        String address = "";
        try{
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for(NetworkInterface intf : interfaces){
                addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                for(InetAddress addr : addrs){
                    if(!addr.isLoopbackAddress() && addr instanceof Inet4Address){
                        address = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase(new Locale("es", "MX"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.w(TAG, "Ex getting IP value " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return address;
    }
```

Agregando el permiso para obtener el estatus de la Wifi.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

y obviamente el de acceso a internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: En parte funciona, acabo de testear en WIFI da la misma IP que el apartado sistema->sobre_telefono->Estado pero si hago que se conecte por tethering usando bluetooth no da la misma ip que se muestra en sistema...

Comment: Este método obtiene la ip del dispositivo, como estas obteniendo la ip del dispositivo al realizar tethering?

Comment: Digamos si el deviceA conecto por wifi router con ADSL se obtiene bien la ip, es cuando el deviceA se conecta por bluettoth a deviceB (donde se conecta con wifi para compartirlo a deviceA) es cuando no concide la ip del panel sistema->estado con esta función

Comment: Testeando ya he averiguado porque retorna diferente valor. No existe una relación directo o no la encontrado que puedes tener varias network interficies asignadas y esa función devuelve la última, si por ejemplo tienes conectas el wifi y después tethering bluetooth dumy,bt-pan,wlan0

Answer (score 1):

Para conocer la IP del HotSpot, prueba preguntando si el nombre de `NetworkInterface` contiene `wlan` o `ap`.

Ejemplo:

```
public String getIP() {

  try {
    for (Enumeration <NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en
      .hasMoreElements();) {
      NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
      if ((intf.getName().contains("wlan")) || (intf.getName().contains("ap"))) {
        for (Enumeration <InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr
          .hasMoreElements();) {
          InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
          if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() &&
            (inetAddress.getAddress().length == 4)) {
            Log.d(TAG, inetAddress.getHostAddress());
            return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (SocketException ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edición**
Me parece para solucionar ese escenario de obtener la dirección IP dependiendo de la conexión establecida, que puede ser `Mobile`,`Wifi`,`Bluetooth`,`Ethernet` etc...

Es primero detectar el tipo de la conexión actual con:

```
public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
}
```

Para detectar conexión WIFI

```
public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
}
```

Para detectar conexión MOBILE

```
public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
}
```

Para detectar conexión BLUETOOTH

```
public static boolean isConnectedBluetooth(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_BLUETOOTH);
}
```

Para detectar conexión tipo ETHERNET

```
public static boolean isConnecteEthernet(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET);
}
```

Acabo de encontrar una función que devuelve la IP de un interficie de red especifica `wlan,bt-plan,eth,rndis..` [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code) y retocándola un poco

```
   public static String getIPAddressIPv4(String id) {
        try {

            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                if (intf.getName().contains(id)) {
                    List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                    for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {

                        if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                            String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                            if (addr instanceof Inet4Address) {
                                return sAddr;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Su uso**

El dispositivo Android puede tener varias interfaces de red conectadas a la vez, se debe especificar que nombre de la interface se quiere obtener su dirección IP.

Para obtener la ip si hay wifi
`getIPAddressIPv4("wlan")`

Para obtener la ip si hay bluetooth-tethering
`getIPAddressIPv4("wlan")`

Para obtener la ip si hay plan de datos mobile
`getIPAddressIPv4("wlan")` => no ser que identificador